# Multiple Regression - VIF

Tags: multiple-regression, multicollinearity, variance-inflation-factor, durbin-watson-test

could anyone help me with my problem - I’m a beginner.

When doing multiple regression and checking for multicollinearity, I have found 2 VIF’s of 17, however, I’ve done some reading and few say it is okay to do multiple regression. Also, my Durbin-Watson is 1.927 which is alright.

Please let me know your thoughts,
Thank you.

Comment: I have two answers on Cross Validated about the myths associated with feature correlation. [(1)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/555163/247274) [(2)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/563175/247274)

Comment: (1) VIF is not a great way to assess multicollinearity, despite its popularity.  (2) Whether 17 is a problem depends also on how many variables and how much data you have, as well as which variables contribute to the near-collinearity and whether their estimates are of interest to you.  These are some of the reasons additional information about your circumstances and goals would be welcome.

Comment: I am interested whether five factors of personality predict overall beliefs about revenge pornography? (Five variables measuring the five factors of personality (i.e., extraversion, agreeableness, conscientiousness, openness, and neuroticism).

I have 500 participants. In regards to near-collinearity and estimates, I am completely lost about this because I am just a beginner. What I do know is that I have tried centralise means of the variables but it came with the same VIF`s. For reference, 3 VIF`s are around 1.5 while the other two are 16.7 and 17.1.