# Semantics: Conditional Distribution vs Marginal Distribution

Tags: regression, conditional-probability, notation

This is something which has always confused me.

Suppose we take a standard statistical regression model:

\begin{equation}
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i
\end{equation}

where:

- $Y_i$ is the response variable
- $X_i$ is the predictor variable
- $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are the coefficients
- $\epsilon_i$ is the error term.

The error term $\epsilon_i$ are assumed to follow a normal distribution with mean 0 and constant variance $\sigma^2$, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
\epsilon_i \sim N(0, \sigma^2)
\end{equation}

Given this information, we can find out the Expected Value of $Y_i$:

\begin{align*}
E(Y_i) &= E(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i) \\
&= E(\beta_0) + E(\beta_1 X_i) + E(\epsilon_i) \\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1 E(X_i) + 0 \\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i
\end{align*}

Given this information, we can also find out the Variance of $Y_i$:

\begin{align*}
Var(Y_i) &= Var(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \epsilon_i) \\
&= Var(\beta_0) + Var(\beta_1 X_i) + Var(\epsilon_i) \\
&= 0 + \beta_1^2 Var(X_i) + \sigma^2 \\
&= 0 +0 + \sigma^2 \\
&=  \sigma^2 \\
\end{align*}

Using the mathematical properties of the Normal Distribution (i.e. linear combinations of Normal Distributions are also Normally Distributed), we usually write the following:

\begin{equation}
P(Y_i) \sim N(\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2)
\end{equation}

**My Question:** When I look at the above formula, I always think that this is referring to the Marginal Probability Distribution of $Y_i$. But since this distribution depends on ${x}_i^T $ , is this not actually the Conditional Distribution?

Thus, I think it would be more correct to write the above formula as:

\begin{equation}
P(Y_i | \mathbf{x}_i) \sim N(\mathbf{x}_i^T \boldsymbol{\beta}, \sigma^2)
\end{equation}

**Can someone please tell me if I am correct?**

Thanks!

- **Note:** Assuming the analysis I provided here is correct - this analysis can serve to clarify one of the common misconceptions in Probability: In a standard regression model - $Y_i$ by itself does NOT need to have a Normal Distribution! But rather, $Y_i | \mathbf{x}_i$ needs to be Normally Distributed!
- This means that if I plot a histogram of the response variable (i.e. $Y_i$) and it does not look Normally Distributed - this in and of itself is not a solid indication that a standard regression model is not suitable. Rather, we need to study the conditional distribution $P(Y_i | \mathbf{x}_i)$ before making such conclusions.

Comment: In your very first formula, the right hand side includes $X_i.$ It therefore either is an expectation parameterized by $X_i$ or it is conditional on $X_i.$ To avoid confusion, your notation on the left ought to reflect that.

Comment: Does [this proposed duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/563175/247274) settle this?

Comment: This was a question that I read prior to posting my question. My question is more about how to correctly write the notation i.e. P(Y) vs P(Y given X) . But I think I understand it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Perhaps, then, it is worth reopening this to allow you to close this out with a self-answer about the notation. Note that self-answers are less common than answers by others but are completely within the etiquette of Cross Validated. I have asked questions on here only to discover the answer and post a self-answer at a later time.

Comment: @Whuber: just to clarify : is the correct notation:  E(Y given X = xi) = b0 + b1*xi ?

Comment: You may use any notation you wish, provided it's sufficiently clear and that you define it.  A conventional notation for *conditional probabilities* would be $\Pr(Y_i\mid x_i)$ while a notation for *parameterized probabilities* would be $\Pr(Y_i;x_i).$ But many people don't even distinguish the two concepts, despite the fact that in the first instance $x_i$ is a random variable and in the second instance it is not.